# Data lost on Serial Port c++

Tags: visual-c++, serialization

In my application written in C++ (Visual Studio 2010) I am reading data on RS232 interface (using a serial to USB converter). The device sends 250 samples/sec data each sample 32 byte long (basically a frame)  with a baud rate of 115200. Frames are separated by two synchronization bytes (0xFFFF). The application reads the bytes from the serial port periodically every 30ms (if bytes are available).

Everything works perfectly fine and I can decode the data in my receiver application accurately. However every now and then, and at random, the data I receive in my application indicates that part of the frame is lost. Once this occurs, most of the subsequent frames arrive with less than 32 bytes in them. The error doesn't go away even if I restart the device. But if I reset the serial port, the error is gone.

I am using 1MB buffers one each for input and output. I have checked for a buffer overflow situation by inquiring about the available bytes on the port which are always less than the 1MB buffer. I have spent days figuring out this problem but so far to no use. Can anybody help me here? Code snippets are below

**// Header file**

```
#ifndef _SERIAL_PORT_H_
#define _SERIAL_PORT_H_

#include <windows.h>
#include <vector>

// ****************************************************************************
// ****************************************************************************

class SerialPort
{
  // **************************************************************************
  // Public data.
  // **************************************************************************

public:
  enum Parity
  {
    NO_PARITY,
    ODD_PARITY,
    EVEN_PARITY
  };

  enum StopBits
  {
    ONE_STOP_BIT,
    TWO_STOP_BITS
  };

  struct PortSettings 
  {
    char portName[256];
    int baudRate;
    Parity parity;
    StopBits stopBits;
    bool hardwareFlowControl;
    unsigned long timeout_s;
    unsigned long timeout_ms;
};

  // **************************************************************************
  // **************************************************************************

public:
  SerialPort();
  ~SerialPort();

  static void enumAvailablePorts(std::vector<int>& ports);
  bool open(const char *portName, int baudRate, Parity parity = NO_PARITY, 
    StopBits stopBits = ONE_STOP_BIT, bool hardwareFlowControl = false);
  bool open(PortSettings s);
  void close();
  bool isOpen();
  const char *getOpenedPortName();

  int bytesAvailable();
  int readData(unsigned char *data, int numBytes);
  int writeData(const char *data, int numBytes);

  // **************************************************************************
  // Private data.
  // **************************************************************************

private:
  static const int RX_BUFFER_SIZE = 1024 * 1024 ;  // = 1 MByte

  PortSettings settings;
  char openedPortName[256];

  // Windows specific variables
  HANDLE handle;
  COMMCONFIG commConfig;
  COMMTIMEOUTS commTimeouts;
};

#endif
```

**// Implementation**

```
// ****************************************************************************

#include "SerialPort.h"

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


// ****************************************************************************
/// Constructor. 
// ****************************************************************************

SerialPort::SerialPort()
{
  strcpy(settings.portName, "None");    // we have "None" here
  settings.baudRate = 115200;
  settings.parity = NO_PARITY;
  settings.stopBits = ONE_STOP_BIT;
  settings.hardwareFlowControl = false;
  settings.timeout_ms = 0;
  settings.timeout_s = 0;

  // Windows specific variables
  handle = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
  strcpy(openedPortName, "");       //new
}

// ****************************************************************************
/// Destructor.
// ****************************************************************************

SerialPort::~SerialPort()
{
  if (isOpen())
  {
    close();
  }
}


// ****************************************************************************
/// Function variant to open the serial port.
// ****************************************************************************

bool SerialPort::open(const char *portName, int baudRate, Parity parity, 
  StopBits stopBits, bool hardwareFlowControl)
{
  PortSettings s;

  strcpy(s.portName, portName);
  s.baudRate = baudRate;
  s.parity = parity;
  s.stopBits = stopBits;
  s.hardwareFlowControl = hardwareFlowControl;
  s.timeout_ms = 0;
  s.timeout_s = 0;

  return open(s);
}

// ****************************************************************************
/// Opens the serial port with the given settings.
// ****************************************************************************

bool SerialPort::open(PortSettings s)
{
  if (isOpen())
  {
    close();
  }

  handle = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
  settings = s;

  // ****************************************************************

  unsigned long confSize = sizeof(COMMCONFIG);
  commConfig.dwSize = confSize;

  handle = CreateFileA(
    s.portName, 
    GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 
    FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE, 
    NULL, 
    OPEN_EXISTING, 0, NULL
  );

  if (handle == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
  {
    return false;
  }

  strcpy(openedPortName, s.portName);

  // ****************************************************************
  // Set the internal buffer size to a big value.
  // ****************************************************************

  unsigned long dwInQueue = RX_BUFFER_SIZE;
  unsigned long dwOutQueue = RX_BUFFER_SIZE;

    if (!SetupComm(handle, dwInQueue, dwOutQueue))
    {
    printf("SerialPort::open() - Unable to setup the COM-port.\n");;
    return false;
    }

  // Prepare the settings structures

  GetCommConfig(handle, &commConfig, &confSize);
  GetCommState(handle, &(commConfig.dcb));

  commConfig.dcb.fBinary = TRUE;
  commConfig.dcb.fInX    = FALSE;
  commConfig.dcb.fOutX   = FALSE;
  commConfig.dcb.fAbortOnError = FALSE;
  commConfig.dcb.fNull   = FALSE;

  // ****************************************************************
  // Set the given baud rate.
  // ****************************************************************

  switch (s.baudRate) 
  {
    case 4800: 
      commConfig.dcb.BaudRate = CBR_4800; 
      break;
    case 9600: 
      commConfig.dcb.BaudRate = CBR_9600; 
      break;
    case 19200: 
      commConfig.dcb.BaudRate = CBR_19200; 
      break;
    case 38400: 
      commConfig.dcb.BaudRate = CBR_38400; 
      break;
    case 57600: 
      commConfig.dcb.BaudRate = CBR_57600; 
      break;
    case 115200: 
      commConfig.dcb.BaudRate = CBR_115200; 
      break;
    case 921600: 
      commConfig.dcb.BaudRate = 921600;   // Must use literals for the value here.
      break;

    default:
      // Invalid baud rate
      close();
      return false;
      break;
  }

  // ****************************************************************
  // Set the number of data bits to 8.
  // ****************************************************************

  commConfig.dcb.ByteSize = 8;

  // ****************************************************************
  // Set the given number of stop bits.
  // ****************************************************************

  switch (s.stopBits) 
  {
    case ONE_STOP_BIT:
      commConfig.dcb.StopBits = ONE_STOP_BIT;
      break;

    case TWO_STOP_BITS:
      commConfig.dcb.StopBits = TWO_STOP_BITS;
      break;
  }

  // ****************************************************************
  // Set the given parity type.
  // ****************************************************************

  switch (s.parity) 
  {
    case NO_PARITY:
      commConfig.dcb.Parity = NOPARITY;
      commConfig.dcb.fParity = FALSE;
      break;

    case EVEN_PARITY:
      commConfig.dcb.Parity = EVENPARITY;
      commConfig.dcb.fParity = TRUE;
      break;

    case ODD_PARITY:
      commConfig.dcb.Parity = ODDPARITY;
      commConfig.dcb.fParity = TRUE;
      break;
  }

  // ****************************************************************
  // Disable flow control.
  // ****************************************************************

  commConfig.dcb.fOutxCtsFlow = FALSE;
  if (s.hardwareFlowControl)
  {
    commConfig.dcb.fRtsControl = DTR_CONTROL_ENABLE;
  }
  else
  {
    commConfig.dcb.fRtsControl = RTS_CONTROL_DISABLE;
  }
  commConfig.dcb.fInX = FALSE;
  commConfig.dcb.fOutX = FALSE;

  // ****************************************************************
  // Set the timeouts.
  // ****************************************************************

  commTimeouts.ReadIntervalTimeout = s.timeout_s*1000 + s.timeout_ms;
  commTimeouts.ReadTotalTimeoutMultiplier = s.timeout_s*1000 + s.timeout_ms;
  commTimeouts.ReadTotalTimeoutConstant = 0;
  commTimeouts.WriteTotalTimeoutMultiplier = s.timeout_s*1000 + s.timeout_ms;
  commTimeouts.WriteTotalTimeoutConstant = 0;
  SetCommTimeouts(handle, &commTimeouts);

  // ****************************************************************
  // Apply the changed configuration.
  // ****************************************************************

  return (bool)SetCommConfig(handle, &commConfig, sizeof(COMMCONFIG));

//  return true;
}

// ****************************************************************************
/// Closes the serial port.
// ****************************************************************************

void SerialPort::close()
{
  if (handle != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
  {
    CloseHandle(handle);
  }
  handle =INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
}

// ****************************************************************************
// ****************************************************************************

bool SerialPort::isOpen()
{
  return (handle != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE);
}

// ****************************************************************************
// ****************************************************************************

const char *SerialPort::getOpenedPortName()
{
  return openedPortName;
}


// ****************************************************************************
/// Returns the number of bytes available for reading.
// ****************************************************************************

int SerialPort::bytesAvailable()
{
  // Determine the number of new bytes.
  COMSTAT comStat;
  DWORD errorMask = 0;

  ClearCommError(handle, &errorMask, &comStat);
  int newBytes = comStat.cbInQue;

  if (newBytes > RX_BUFFER_SIZE/2)
  {
    printf("\nSerial Port buffer is more than half full"); 
  }

  return newBytes;
}


// ****************************************************************************
/// Tries to read the given number of bytes from the RX buffer. The actual 
/// number of read bytes is returned.
// ****************************************************************************

int SerialPort::readData(unsigned char *data, int numBytes)
{
  DWORD bytesRead;
  ReadFile(handle, (void*)data, numBytes, &bytesRead, NULL);

  return (int)bytesRead;
}


// ****************************************************************************
/// Writes data out on the serial port.
/// \return The actual number of bytes written.
// ****************************************************************************

int SerialPort::writeData(const char *data, int numBytes)
{
  if (isOpen() == false)
  {
    return 0;
  }

  DWORD bytesWritten;

  if (WriteFile(handle, (void*)data, (DWORD)numBytes, &bytesWritten, NULL)) 
  {
    // Flush the bytes
    FlushFileBuffers(handle);
    return (int)bytesWritten;
  }
  else 
  {
    return 0;
  }
}


// ****************************************************************************
```

**//Application**

```
main()
{

SerialPort port; 

port.open(emgPortName, 115200, SerialPort::NO_PARITY, 
      SerialPort::ONE_STOP_BIT, true); 

// repeat following code every 30ms

int numBytesAvailable = port->bytesAvailable();


  if (numBytesAvailable >= RAW_BUFFER_SIZE)
  {  
    printf("\nWarning!!!!!!!!!!!\nSerial port buffer overflow!!!"); 
    numBytesAvailable = RAW_BUFFER_SIZE; 
  }  

  port->readData(rawEmgBuffer, numBytesAvailable); 


}
```

Comment: Baud rate switch is absurd, Windows just uses the numeric value.  Also, forget about using `cbInQue`.  Just use `ReadFile` in overlapped mode.  Saves steps and works very reliably.

Comment: You are ignoring the need for proper error reporting, do *not* call ClearCommError() without checking the errors it returns.  The "Serial port buffer overflow!" message is not accurate.   Handshaking setup is broken, no RTS control, you'll certainly risk overrun errors.  No consideration for synchronization, once you lose a byte the show is over.  Hard to get started reliably as well.

Comment: @BenVoigt The application doesn't use any write function. Do I still need to use overlapped IO? I have never worked with overlapped IO (in fact not even Serial ports before)

Comment: @HansPassant I am just capturing a whole bunch of data including the snychronization bytes and then construct frames from it offline. Can you elaborate a little more on the techniques you mentioned and why do I need them?

Comment: That comment doesn't help me help you.  Fix the error reporting, fix the handshaking, probably good enough to get it in production.

Comment: @user3411355: No, you don't actually need overlapped I/O here.

Answer (score 0):

I cringe when I see code like

```
int numBytesAvailable = port->bytesAvailable();
port->readData(rawEmgBuffer, numBytesAvailable);
```

That approach I mostly see in [very broken C# implementations](http://www.sparxeng.com/blog/software/must-use-net-system-io-ports-serialport).

The *right* way to read available data from a serial port is much, much simpler:

- Set the read timeout to zero using `SetCommTimeouts` (only needs to be done once).
- Call `ReadFile`, passing in your buffer and buffer size.  It will return immediately with only the number of bytes already received, up to a maximum of the buffer size you gave it.  The number of bytes copied to your buffer is known via the fourth argument.

If you find that your buffer was wholly filled, you might want to read again more quickly (e.g. right after processing the first chuck, without waiting for your next timer callback).  If you find the buffer empty, you might tell the user to check their connection.

Overlapped I/O is a good addition to your toolbox because it allows you to get an event as soon as data becomes available.  But if you are getting good enough performance with polling (and your polling loop isn't busy-waiting), then a blocking read with zero timeout is ideal.

Comment: I tried this technique. However the random data loss is still there. My internal buffer is 1MB. Using the ClearCommError() command I checked and the number of new bytes are never more than the 1MB (not even 1/4th). Even with a 4MB internal buffer and increasing the speed of reading the serial port, the error still happen (of course at random). Am I looking at the right place for to identify the problem?

Comment: @user3411355: You aren't reopening the port between calls to ReadFile are you?  Repeated calls to ReadFile will get you every byte that is correctly received by the PC serial port.  If you are still losing data then either (1) the peer isn't sending it (check for overflowed ring buffers in embedded code, etc), (2) you have timing skew caused by inexact baud rates and resulting in occasional framing errors, (3) the line is noisy, (4) handshaking and flow control aren't correctly configured.  Have you looked at the serial line with a scope?  Are the missing bytes actually on the wire?

Comment: No. I am not re-opening the port between the calls to ReadFile. Unfortunately, I don't have access to the embedded code to check what is going on at the sender side. Also no scope available. The only hint is that as soon as I reset the serial port (in my software), the error is gone. Incorrect baud-rate looks interesting but then shouldn't the framing error occur regularly after specific interval? while here the framing error sometimes occur after 5min. Sometimes not even in 60min. I don't have access to the embedded code.  don't know how to implement handshaking and flow control.

Comment: @user3411355: The other thing that seems likely to be is that you're not resynchronizing properly.  Remember that serial ports are raw byte streams, there is no meaning to the quantity of data returned from a single read call or the artificial boundaries between read calls.  So if you have 32 byte messages and read in 32 byte blocks, it's entirely possible for a message to be split across two blocks, and a single byte error will permanently change the position of that split, until the port is reset.  So make sure your code can deal with message reassembly.

Comment: I attempt to read all bytes available on the port into a buffer not blocks of 32 bytes. Then I construct the frames from the data read in an offline manner. i.e, remove the synch bytes and construct the frame. I am convinced this wont be the problem.

Comment: @user3411355: Maybe one of the bytes in your data is being treated as a special value and removed from the data stream.  If the byte appeared in many messages, then all those messages would be corrupted.  For example, if you have XON/XOFF flow control enabled, then any byte matching the XON or XOFF value would be treated as a control byte, not data.  For binary data transfer make sure that XON/XOFF is disabled.

Comment: @user3411355: In general, using `GetCommConfig` or `GetCommState` is a bad idea.  You almost never want to inherit random serial port settings configured by a previous program.  Start with a blank slate.

Comment: @user3411355: It looks like `fDsrSensitivity` could be causing your missing data.